# Les formes « je vas » et « je vais »

Tags: prononciation, histoire, conjugaison

Quand est-ce que la forme « je vais » a remplacé « je vas », (1) dans le bon usage; (2) dans l'usage populaire en Europe?

Pour quelle raison écrit-on *vais* alors qu'on prononce le mot avec un *e* fermé?

Answer (score 10):

Comme on l'explique dans *Le bon usage* (Grevisse et Goosse, *ed. de Boeck/Duculot*) au §833 (note *H2*), « *je vas* » relevait du **français distingué jusqu'au 19**<sup>**e**</sup> : « *je ne sais où je vas* » (Prince [De Ligne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles-Joseph_de_Ligne), 1735-1814, ds. [*Mémoires*](https://books.google.com/books?id=aSsDAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22je%20ne%20sais%20o%C3%B9%20je%20vas%22%20de%20ligne&pg=PA72#v=onepage&q=%22je%20ne%20sais%20o%C3%B9%20je%20vas%22%20de%20ligne&f=false)). On trouve aussi un exemple au [*Godefroy*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/complement-godefroy/76/8/aler) (« *Je m'en vas disner à Mante et reviendrai coucher icy, puis demain j'y iray du tout.* », [*Recueil des lettres missives de Henri IV*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=0Fz-xvfvjgQC&dq=lettre%20missive%20henri%20iV%20t%203&pg=PA755#v=onepage&q&f=false), 1593). Toujours selon la même note au *LBU*,  [*George Sand*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Sand) (Mme Amantine Aurore Lucile Dupin, baronne Dudevant) serait restée fidèle à « *je vas* » jusqu'à la fin de sa vie. En effet :

[image]

<sup>« *J'ai trouvé hier un délicieux cocher qui revient me prendre aujourd'hui. **Je vas** chez Juliette qui est logée bien haut, mais en belle vue et un charmant petit nid.* [...] » (George Sand, [*Papiers de George Sand. III-XXVIII Journal intime. Année 1867*](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b53030268z/f137.item.zoom), extrait de l'entrée du 22 septembre - voir [retranscription](https://www.yumpu.com/fr/document/view/16533016/agendas-les-amis-de-george-sand/57))</sup>

On peut jeter un coup d'oeil au [corpus écrit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je%20vas%2Cje%20vais&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20vas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20vais%3B%2Cc0) de Google; selon ces données, ce n'est plus en usage à l'écrit depuis longtemps. Mais on le trouve dans les dictionnaires de l'[Académie](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/dicos/pubdico1look.pl?strippedhw=aller) 5<sup>e</sup> (1798) et 6<sup>e</sup> (1835, on mentionne *rarement*). C'est devenu un français *populaire* que Marcel Proust, par exemple, mettra dans la [bouche](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Du_c%C3%B4t%C3%A9_de_chez_Swann/Partie_1) d'un personnage comme celui de [Françoise](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7oise_%28%C3%80_la_recherche_du_temps_perdu%29), inspiré de sa servante (« *Je vas seulement voir si mon feu ne s’éteint pas.* », Proust, *Du côté de chez Swann*, 1913). Toujours au *LBU*, on note d'autres exemples de ce genre d'emploi chez Genevoix ([*Raboliot*](https://books.google.com/books?id=MyNMAAAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3AxKTE5mM3azEC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22je%20vas%22), 1925) et Bernanos ([Ouine](https://books.google.com/books?id=hWInAAAAMAAJ&dq=editions%3A4xhAX_gpTOAC&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22je%20vas%22), 1946).<sup>1</sup>

Voir notes en fin d'entrée au *TLFi* à [*aller*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller) pour des indices sur la phonétique.

---

<sub>1. Au Québec c'est du registre familier, à l'oral; on l'[entendra](https://applis.flsh.usherbrooke.ca/cfpq/index.php/transcriptions/recherche/mot?typerecherche=0&choixcorpus=0&Transcriptions%5Bligne%5D=je+vas&yt0=CHERCHER).</sub>

Comment: Et puis suivant le taux d’[**ivresse**](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/livrogne-drunkard.html) (ou peut-être plutôt le mot qu’il fallait rimer avec), les poètes (Belges, au moins) se servaient des deux, même jusqu'au XXe !

Comment: Très bonne réponse concernant *je vas*. Je ne savais pas que c'était resté courant en France jusque dans le 20e siècle.

Answer (score 3):

Je vas, c'est du patois, cela est d'usage tant que la population garde vivantes les formes qui font la richesse de la langue _ cela s'applique aussi à l'argot et à toutes les langues dont les langues à usage officiel:poetiques (iran/chine par exemple).
La date exacte d'extinction est donné lors d'une interdiction.
je vais ne se prononce pas e fermé car j'y va, j'y vais. vais prononcé e fermé voudrais dire je vois.
"Le bon usage" est une des meilleures référence qu'y soit mais parle de l'écrit non de l'oral et du francais non du patois.