# Mettons que j'ai une question d'étymologie

Tags: étymologie, origine-ou-raison, registre-familier, canada

Il y a une construction typique en français canadien familier (je ne sais pas si elle est également commune en France), par exemple:

> J'y ai pas tout dit, mais mettons que c't'assez pour qu'à comprenne.

Je serais curieux de connaître l'étymologie de "mettons que". Si je devine, l'origine serait soit simplement une utilisation de "mettre", on pourrait substituer "postulons que" (quoique le ton devient beaucoup plus formel!), ou bien ce serait une corruption de "admettons que". Est-ce que l'origine de cette expression familière est documentée?

Comment: Attention que si le "mettons" ne me paraît pas incongru (en français de Belgique), le reste de la phrase est par contre très connoté français canadien. "J'y ai pas tout dit" (= je ne lui ai pas tout dit) n'est pas du tout idiomatique de ce côté de l'atlantique, de même que "pour qu'à comprenne" (= pour qu'il/elle comprenne).

Comment: "De ce côté de l'Atlantique" est un peu exagéré : l'usage de /i/ pour "lui" me semble assez fréquent en France (mais je confirme qu'il est absent en Belgique)

Comment: J'ai utilisé le français familier que je connais. J'avais d'abord tenté une phrase en registre courant à l'exception de "mettons que", mais je la trouvais beaucoup trop inauthentique. De toute façon cela a peu d'importance pour l'essentiel de la question. Et @LaurentS., attention, "qu'à" = "qu'elle" et non pas "qu'il", ce qui serait plutôt "qu'y" ;)

Comment: J'ai rajouté ce commentaire car la phrase est introduite par "il y a une construction typique..;" et que personnellement, hormis le "mettons", je ne trouve rien de très typique. Concernant le "j'y", j'ai en effet peut-être été un peu trop large ou catégorique, mais l'emploi de y pour remplacer "lui" ou "leur" reste selon moi à la foi très familier ET daté...

Comment: Pour ma part, j'aurais écris "mettons que j'aie" car le subjonctif me semble naturel ici : on dit bien : "mettons que je sois (...)". Évidemment, pour l'oreille, pas de différence!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La tournure est-elle principalement canadienne-française ? Vraisemblablement pas. Une courte recherche chez Gallica nous indique qu’elle existe aussi en Europe :

> HENRIETTE. — Comment ? vous ne voyez pas ? Mettons que les âmes dont M. le curé a la garde représentent mes moutons d’autrefois ; et que les habitants de la commune représentent les oies de Jeannette.
>       <sup>—*Révélations d'une servante de curé*, LAGUÊPE (Paris, 1877)</sup>
> — Trois cents bâtards par semaine et rien que pour Paris, c’est à dire cinquante-deux fois trois cents par an, soit quinze mille six cents enfants; n’est-ce pas vraiment effrayant ? — **Mettons que** nous exagérons et qu’il y ait seulement dix mille de ces pauvres petits êtres pour deux millions d’habitants, cela nous donnerait, si la proportion était égale pour toute la France, cinq mille par million, soit cent quatre-vingt mille pour les trente-six millions d’habitants de notre pays. Là encore, diminuons si vous le voulez, et **mettons qu**’il n’y en ait que cent mille par an, n’est-ce pas encore un chiffre à faire réfléchir l’esprit le plus égoïste, l’homme le plus blasé, et à le forcer à reconnaître que la recherche de la paternité s’impose.
>       <sup>—*Les prolétariennes : lettres ouvertes aux ouvriers. 4e lettre*, LAFRANCHISE (Lyon, 1898)</sup>

Elle est aussi enregistrée, quoique déclarée *familière*, au TLFi, à l’article [**mettre**](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/mettre) :

> − *Mettez que, mettons que* + prop. **Admettons que, supposons que.** *Ah! Mam'zelle, je n'ai point dit que vous étiez un singe : et je me suis mal exprimé pour cela, **mettez que** je suis un âne, un cornichon, une oie* (Ségur, Mémoires d’un âne, 1860). ***Mettons que** je n'ai rien dit* (Becque, Corbeaux, 1882). ***Mettons que** vous soyez pour de bon le capitaine d'un véritable navire* (Audiberti, Quoat, 1946).

L’hypothèse d’une forme tirée d’une [aphérèse](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/aph%C3%A9r%C3%A8se) d’***admettons que*** est séduisante, mais demande à être testée. Ma perception personnelle de l’expression m’indique qu’elle pourrait s’apparenter à ***Posons que***, ***Établissons que***, ***Supposons que***, ***Admettons que***, mais qu’elle n’est pas systématiquement remplaçable dans tous les cas par l’ensemble de ces termes, mais je me suis parfois fait piéger par mes a-priori.

Pour tester, donc, je propose de trouver un exemple où ***Admettons que*** ne soit pas approprié. Pas facile, mais voici du moins un exemple qui, à défaut d’être entièrement convaincant, sème du moins un doute :

> Mais, repris-je, comment, diable, se fait-il que ce soit là précisément ce que je contemplais, et surtout qu’il y ait tant d’analogie entre un peuple et des Girouettes ? **Mettons que** je n’aie eu qu’une vision ; comment se fait-il que les hommes agissent précisément, comme les Girouettes agissaient ?
>       <sup>—*Dissertation sur les girouettes et les marionnettes, par le bonhomme Thomas, concierge logé dans la lanterne du dôme des Invalides, avec des notes, et suivie de ses réflexions sur la manière de lire l’histoire et d’apprécier les conquérans*, par Jean-Baptiste GOURIET (1774-1855)</sup>

On sent ici qu’en **mettant** de l’avant une hypothèse, le narrateur n’y croit pas tout à fait, ou plutôt pas du tout. Il le fait bien plutôt par acquit de conscience que par sincère croyance en la réalité de sa supposition. Il l’admet au discours, certes, mais de façon très temporaire, simplement pour la mettre en pièces. Il ressemble davantage en ceci au mathématicien qui introduit les pièces d’une [démonstration par l’absurde](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisonnement_par_l%27absurde) en utilisant [***Supposons que***](https://www.deleze.name/marcel/culture/Racine_de_2_est_irrationnel/racine_de_2_est_irrationnel.htm.html). Il n’admet pas vraiment la réalité de ce qu’il présente, car il sait d’avance que tout cela aboutira à une contradiction grossière. Il admet plutôt seulement que l’on puisse invoquer par l’esprit un état du monde pour lequel ce serait possible.

Le second exemple du TLFi pourrait aussi servir :

> **Mettons que** je n’ai rien dit.

Cette utilisation me semble se rapprocher davantage de ***Convenons que*** que d’***Admettons que***.

Ici encore, c’est ouvert à la discussion. Mais le tour me semble au final assez logique par lui-même pour ne pas devoir requérir qu’il doive provenir d’une contraction d’***Admettons que***.

Comment: Vraiment une excellente recherche ! Souvent on pense que c'est surtout du Canada parce qu'on a d'autres marqueurs dans la phrase qui donnent cette impression. Je pensais ça par exemple pour _je vas_.

Comment: [Je vas/Je vais](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14341/les-formes-je-vas-et-je-vais), une excellente interrogation qui ne me serait pas venu à l'esprit de poser, et une excellente réponse par un ancien avatar de Shiva.

Answer (score 1):

Cet usage du verbe « mettre » existe aussi  dans le français français.

Le (TLFi) dit ceci  :

> c) Familier ; 
>    Mettez que, mettons que + prop. Admettons que, supposons que.
>   [Mettons entre deux élém. de la prop.] Disons, supposons.

Le dictionnaire ne mentionne pas que ce soit une forme contractée ; cela peut se défendre ; cependant dans ces situations d'incertitude caractérisées par une spécification manquante, un détail oublié et douteux, il est pratique courante, lorsque le soucis d'exactitude n'est pas grand,  de remédier à cette sorte d'inconvénient par le remplissage du vide constaté avec un à peu près ; on dit alors à la place de « écrivons ceci ou cela » ou « disons ceci ou cela », « mettons ceci ou cela » ; il s'agit très précisément du verbe « mettre » dans son sens littéral. N'est-il pas tout à fait plausible que le verbe dans son acception de « supposer », « admettre » et « dire » soit issue de cet état de chose ? Si convaincante que soit l'hypothèse de la contraction elle ne repose pas, autant qu'on sache, sur autre chose qu'une forte similarité. D'ailleurs, on peut se demander comment les utilisateurs du langage auraient pu être instigués à l'usage d'une contraction dans ce cas particulier d'occurrence de « admettre », le seul en existence qui occasionne la contraction (la fréquence importante de l'usage ?). En l'absence de faits rapportés de source sûre on ne peut pas conclure. Le dictionnaire de l'Académie n'est pas plus informatif sur ce point.

Answer (score -2):

> Mettons que

Est bien la forme contractée de **Admettons que**.

Il n'existe pas, à ma connaissance, de documentation à ce sujet.

Comment: Mettons que votre première affirmation soit vraie (*mettons que* est bien la forme contractée de *admettons que*). Mettons maintenant que votre seconde affirmation soit aussi vraie (vous ne connaissez aucune documentation à ce sujet). Pour concilier les deux, je me vois obligé de conclure que vous êtes l'inventeur du tour et qu'il n'existait pas avant vous. Mettons que j'ai comme un doute.