# L'emploi argotique du mot "garagiste"

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, argot, littérature

Bonjour,

Je suis tombé sur ce passage dans *Guignol's Band* :

"Encore une autre raie sur le bras!... À moi tout le bonheur! **Garagiste** je suis! À moi la volaille! À moi la tronche etcétéra!... Où que je vas (*sic*) les mettre?... Ça me fait mal!..." (CÉLINE, 2015, p. 122)

Comme il s'agit de la description du milieu de la prostitution à Londres, je ne comprends pas très bien le sens du mot ***garagiste*** dans ce cas.

Peut-on supposer que dans l'argot de la prostitution "garagiste" est un synonyme de "maquereau" ?

Comment: À propos de ***je vas*** : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14351/1109

Answer (score 3):

En argot un **garage** est le lieu où travaille un(e) prostitué(e).

Je ne connaissais pas **garagiste** mais il est tout à fait probable que Céline emploie le terme comme synonyme de taulier, je dis plutôt taulier (propriétaire du lieu) que maquereau (n'est pas propriétaire du lieu).

Voir [l'argot de la prostitution](https://www.languefrancaise.net/Usage/2?order=title).