# « Je vas » remplacé par « je vais »

Tags: prononciation, verbes, orthographe, france, évolution

**La Petite Fadette**, George Sand

> C’est possible que je t’aie haï un peu,
> répondit la petite Fadette ; mais si cela a été, cela
> n’est plus à partir d’aujourd’hui, et je vas te dire
> pourquoi, Landry.

On trouve 9 cas de « je vais » et 5 de « je vas » dans le livre.

Il existe sur le site FSE  une réponse à la question à propos de [l'histoire](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14341/17649) du remplacement de « je vas » par « je vais » et la [réponse principale](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14351/17649) y répond en apportant plusieurs détails intéressants. Cependant, la raison du remplacement n'est pas abordée.

Existe-t-il une explication généralement reconnue ou des hypothèses concernant le pourquoi de ce changement ? Par exemple, comme il est reconnu que « je vas » faisait partie du parler distingué, peut-on inférer que le remplacement aurait été amené par  la pression du parler populaire et quelle était l'origine de cette forme dans le parler populaire ?

Une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14375/17649) affirme que « je vas » était du patois ; comment se fait-il alors qu'elle était reconnue comme distinguée et utilisée par la couche supérieure de la société ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je n'ai pas l'expertise pour répondre sauf pour dire, en paraphrasant [le mémoire de Bergeron-Maguire](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52614/26366), qu'à l'origine on avait les formes *je vois/vais*, que la première fut rejetée et qu'ensuite s'est installé au 16<sup>e</sup> *je vas* et son intérêt était d'avoir une morphologie régulière avec la deuxième et la troisième personne (*tu vas, il va*). C'est Vaugelas qui dit que la Cour disait *je va* et déjà à son époque son propos était remis en question. Mais le français de la métropole avait adopté *je vas* et la conjugaison *je vais* était sentie comme populaire ou régionale ou celle des milieux lettrés, « probablement » parce qu'elle reprenait la forme « traditionnelle ». Mais dès le 17<sup>e</sup> au théâtre l'emploi de *je vas* est associé dans la « très grande majorité des cas à des personnages appartenant aux couches populaires », comme le personnage de *Fadette*.

Il y a donc éventuellement eu un « revirement » (prescription, standardisation ou autrement évolution) et j'y vois comme une espèce de « chassé-croisé » de [phénomènes](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langages-2016-3-page-71.htm) [diastratiques](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/diastratique) (classe sociale des locuteurs) et [diatropiques](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/diatopique) (origine des locuteurs) dans l'évolution de cette conjugaison. C'est à mon avis la raison pour laquelle les deux réponses de la question liée sont bonnes...

Et pour un profane comme moi, ce genre de situation est non sans rappeler ce qui s'est passé avec le fameux propos du roi « Moe, le Roe » après la Révolution en ce sens que ce qui était *distingué* soudainement ne l'était plus :

[image]

[ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 60, intégralement ]

Answer (score 0):

Sources utiles à la réflexion :

[image]

[ Myriam Bergeron-Maguire. [*Le français en Haute-Normandie aux 17e et 18e siècles : aspects lexicaux, phonétiques et grammaticaux.*](https://hal.univ-lorraine.fr/tel-01751804) Linguistique. Université de Lorraine, 2014. Français. NNT : 2014LORR0329. tel-01751804 ]

[image]

[ *Le verbe français: étude morphologique*, Pierre Fouché, 1967, p. 425, accès incomplet ]

Voir aussi la [carte 23 (*je vais*) de l'ALF](http://lig-tdcge.imag.fr/cartodialect5/#/visualiseur).

Comment: J'espère que ces sources pourront servir à quelqu'un d'autre pour produire une meilleure réponse que la mienne.